Android square screen how to use portrait layout?
I need to adapt a square screen(1200px * 1200px, 160dpi), use context.resources.configuration.orientation found out it's a landscape orientation. How do I force a portrait layout?
I've already tried some methods and none of them work:

activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
add layout-square resource


You can try following solution -
In AndroidManifest.xml
Add following attribute to your activity tag -> android:screenOrientation="potrait"
Or
In active
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTAIT)
}

